# Can I ask to have a block or left alone by a user?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, status-declined, site-enhancement

I have a user who is always the **first to close** and down vote most if not all my work if you can call it that. I do not want him on my stuff. I truly feel harassed even though he has not really broke any rules. I just want him to leave me and my stuff alone forever! What can I do?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281831/could-a-levitron-work-above-earth

Comment: We don't make posts about users.

Comment: Jen, perhaps it is time to ask if Physics Stack Exchange is the right place for your thoughts at this time. Not that we're telling you to go, but you don't seem to be happy here and your content is not (as evidence by the voting) in line with what the bulk of the users expect. Many (almost all, really) of your recent questions have been about the feasibility of vague-but-insanely-ambitious engineering schemes for which you haven't done even the roughest of back-of-the-envelope computations. That kind of thing just *isn't* going to be well received on this site.

Comment: @dmckee I love this site but there are aspects of it that can be improved on like capping the amount of down votes you can give to a single user. I accept critical thinking but high reputation users should not be so fast to discourage new users by closing and down voting answers before less advanced users have a chance answer.

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9182/

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6754/

Comment: Jen, you're not a new user. You've made nearly 300 posts (though half are deleted either by your own action, by vote from the review queues, or by automated processes). At this point you should have a pretty good idea what the standards are. You have the same chance to write good posts as every other user, and you get to be subjected to the same crowd-sourced evaluation as every other user.

Comment: @DavidZ I have been learning and improving on existing posts. There are far from the complex questions I have seen here, but over time they will get better.

Comment: @peterh i removed the accepted answer if you want to delete it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a user that frequents SE sites intermittently (and with less reputation than most, including yourself), please interpret my upcoming critique as independent from the high-rep user/users you believe are targeting you.  You seem to be intentionally ignoring the community's critique, falsely assuming that you are the victim.

I appreciate your curiosity - it will serve you well if you put in the work required to graduate from curiosity to knowledge.  But understand that knowledge comes via research, frustration, research, work, work, work, then questions and answers.

Your current asking criteria deserves downvotes, and I have personally downvoted at least two of your posts (purely on their content).  Avoiding debates on a per question basis, Ill simply say that your questions contained spelling errors, incorrect and/or out of context information with no references, and no visible effort on your part.
To me (and I presume to other users), that is a clear sign of disrespect to the community.  You should expect to spend as much time and effort to [research, research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), contemplate, then write your question as the answer you hope to receive.  To be clear, a link and/or picture helps, but only to clarify concepts - dont mistake them for research or effort.

Please appreciate the amount of time and effort it takes to research, develop a (correct) answer, and then write that answer in order to help you.

The last is especially true for the monumental questions you have asked recently:  Do you think succinct answers are possible?  Do you think its reasonable to spend ~2 minutes asking a whimsical question, and expect an answer that essentially invents/validates a non-existent technology (in a page or two, no less)!?

Questions are great.  Thats why we all choose to participate here.  But realize that when you ask a question, the community expects you to care enough about your question to try, really try to answer it yourself.  Do every calculation you know you should.  Read every article you can find.  Struggle to find the answer on your own, then ask.  Questions should articulate what you dont understand in order to continue answering your larger question - remember, its your question, not ours.

Given multiple closed and downvoted questions, I urge you to reconsider your asking criteria - to reiterate @dmckee, realize that a single user cannot be responsible for closure and multiple downvotes.  I think you should accept that users really do vote on content, not on personal grudges.

I sincerely hope this is not recieved as an attack against you personally - its intended to be a candid rebuttal of your question - and I look forward to your future contributions.

Answer (score 18):

### No. You can't.

Every user with the requisite rep is entitled to vote on the content you post. That's by design: we use a crowd-sourced evaluation. There may exist users that cast more downvotes than up, and that is allowed. It just means that user has very stringent standards of quality; as long as those standards are applied evenly the user is free to continue in that mode.

Nor is the problem that you have that a single user is after you: if it was you would never get more than a single down-vote.

The problem that you *are* having is that a lot of the content you post is *widely* viewed as failing to live up to the standards of Physics Stack Exchange. I am being rather blunt here because you have posted to meta several times and have apparently not taken subtle suggestions to heart.

Downvotes are not a criticism of you as a person, but they are a criticism of the post on which they are applied.

Comment: He is a physics bully. I can sense it when he down-votes in seconds after I post a question or answer. Other users will  pass on a question that already has a down vote. I don't need all my questions and answers I've put effort and thought in to start with a negative because of him. He can just do nothing.

Comment: Jen, we don't make posts about individual users. That's simply part of the ethos: we focus on content not personalities. We're not talking about some other particular person here.